# What are these other relics in the movie Thor?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-2011

We see a few artifacts in the movie Thor which are not identified.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any idea what these artifacts are?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Odin's Trophy Room, also called the Vault has held a number of powerful artifacts captured in battles against the enemies of Asgard. This is part of the Marvel Cinematic Universe #199999. Some of these items include:**

- **The Orb of Agamotto** - an orb with the power of clairvoyance able to cross dimensional realms. It can be blocked by powerful sorcerers. In the canon Marvel Universe #616 the device is in the possession of Dr. Strange.
- **The Tablet of Life and Time** - On the tablet was a biochemical formula for a serum, the so-called Lifeline Formula, which could rejuvinate, heal and grant its user the chance to reach the full evolutionary potential of its race turning the user into an immortal near omnipotent being. It is part of a larger series of tablets including the tablets of Death and Entropy and Order and Chaos. These items were believed to have been created by the ancient civilizations of Atlantis and Lemuria.
- **The Warlock's Eye** - A powerful, mystical weapon used unsuccessfully against Odin, Thor and the Warriors Three during an invasion of Asgard.
- **The Infinity Gauntlet** (displayed below) - An item of immeasurable power with the ability to alter the very fabric of reality itself, assuming it has all six of the Infinity Stones. This object is a fake, presumably fabricated at the behest of Odin. The real Infinity Gauntlet is in the possession of the Mad Titan Thanos, as seen at during the post-credits scene in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*.
- **The Eternal Flame** (displayed below) - Stolen by Odin and his brothers, this weapon was reputed to be the final element needed by the Fire Giant Surtur to ignite his sword and potentially begin Ragnarok.
- **The Cask of Ancient Winters** (not displayed here) - When opened, it releases powerful arctic weather that is capable of freezing anything in its path; killing humans and immobilizing Asgardians. This weapon is capable of even stopping the magic of Odin and is potentially one of the most dangerous in the trophy room.
- **Twilight Sword** (displayed below) – Created by Surtur using the energy of the exploding home galaxy of the Korbinites, it was intended to set the universe afire. Later used as a power source by Loki & Morgan Le Fay.

[image: Artifacts of the Vault of Odin]

[image: Twilight Sword in Surtur's hands]

Comment: On the Infinity Gauntlet - "This object was stolen and believed to be in the hands of Thanos, the Mad Titan." - Where was this stated in one of the films? I was thinking it should still be there.

Comment: Ya, I'm pretty sure the Infinity Gauntlet is still there. Though I have no doubt it'll be stolen by Thanos at some point in the MCU

Comment: As of the end of Avengers: age of Ultron, the Infinity Gauntlet wielded by Thanos is *different* to that in Odins Vault - Odin's is a right hand, whereas Thanos's is a left.

Comment: Does the Gauntlet give the wearer powers of any kind when there are no stones installed in it? Perhaps Thanos' gauntlet is one he made himself. This would be easier than invading Asgard and stealing the gauntlet that was seen in Odin's vault. Just speculating - openly admit to not being a comics expert of any kind.

Comment: @JackBNimble Well, we got an update on the guantlet in _Thor: Ragnarok_

Comment: Worth noting that in the comics the gauntlet was indeed created by Thanos to harness the power of the infinity stones, and is essentially powerless without them.

Comment: Except that most of the stuff in the vault is fake, according to Hela.

Comment: The only artifact which we have been assured a fake was the Infinity Gauntlet. The Cask of Winters we know for certain to be real. The Eternal Flame was also real.

Comment: Which was the one she called "weak"?

Comment: The Cask of Winters.

Comment: Perhaps you would be willing to update this answer with a Ragnarok update to include the Tesseract and Surtur's crown.