# Why does Stark not use the same material for his suit as Captain America's shield is made of?

Tags: avengers, captain-america, iron-man, marvel

Caps Shield can withstand most projectiles and absorb quite a bit of force (Hulks fist, Thors Hammer to name two of the tougher ones). Wouldn't it make sense for Stark to use the same material for his suit?

If this was already answered somewhere, I am sorry, but I didn't find it...

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/43723/why-didnt-iron-man-make-a-vibranium-armor

Comment: ok, seems I needed to search for Vibranium to find the answer to my question. Accepted the dupe, shall i delete it myself?

Comment: Well, metals have properties other than strength. Why aren't airplanes made of tungsten?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know his shield is made of vibranium adamantium alloy, both extremely rare materials. There is simply not enough of them to make a complete suit.